# Display only one div and hide the rest using index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a function that will fadeIn() a div with class image on hover on another class. However there are multiple divs from each class and would like to have each div correspond to another. I havet hought about using index() to get the inex number of each class and then equal each index number to only display the one corresponding.

To clarify I'll express it as code:

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="woot"></div>
        <div class="woot"></div>
        <div class="woot"></div>
        <div class="woot"></div>
        <div class="woot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="img_container">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
```

The idea is that when hovering the first woot div it will display the first image div, if hovering the second one it will display the second one and the same process for the rest.

Comment: What do you mean by `hover`? Display as long as the mouse is over it?

Comment: Yes, I mean display while the mouse is over the div.

Comment: @LcLk What I have tries is pretty much nothing, I am not too experienced with JavaScript, but I am guessing it would be done that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this solution, you got to set ALL the `.img_container div` to `display:none`.

#### CSS

```
.img_container div{display:none;}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.container div').on('mouseenter', function(){

  var indx = $(this).index();
  $('.img_container div').eq(indx).show();

})

$('.container div').on('mouseleave', function(){

  var indx = $(this).index();
  $('.img_container div').eq(indx).hide();

})
```

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sz7am8Lt/.

---

With this solution you got to set ALL the `.img_container div` to `visibility:hidden`.

#### CSS

```
.img_container div{visibility:hidden;}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.container div').on('mouseenter', function(){

  var indx = $(this).index();
  $('.img_container div').eq(indx).css('visibility','visible');

})

$('.container div').on('mouseleave', function(){

  var indx = $(this).index();
  $('.img_container div').eq(indx).css('visibility','hidden');

})
```

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sz7am8Lt/1/.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>

//use css selection in jquery


 $('container span:nth-child(1))
 $('container span:nth-child(2))
 $('container span:nth-child(3))
 $('container span:nth-child(4))


I hope this will help you.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".woot").hover(
    function() {
      $(".image:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").show();
    },
    function() {
      $(".image:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").hide();
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.woot {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="woot"></div>
  <div class="woot"></div>
  <div class="woot"></div>
  <div class="woot"></div>
  <div class="woot"></div>
</div>
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="image">1</div>
  <div class="image">2</div>
  <div class="image">3</div>
  <div class="image">4</div>
  <div class="image">5</div>
</div>
```